# iOS MDM - supervise a device but allow users their own iTunes account?

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-configurator

This is my first ever question on stack overflow despite having read thousands of pages here over the years

My question is pretty basic but I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere. What I want to know is whether is it possible, using Apple Configurator 2 and Meraki MDM to configure a set of iPads so that they are being supervised (for locating, unlocking & wiping) and have some apps pre-installed but are not signed in with an iTunes or iCloud account. We want the people we are issuing the iPads to to be able to sign with their own accounts and utilise the devices for essentially anything they want.

Any good up to date resources on getting started with MDM would also be welcome, I'm finding a lot of the material I encounter to be out of date, more complicated that I need, or patchy.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Ben

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your request for "Any good up to date resources..." is off topic because _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._.

Comment: Also, this is a question about admin tools, not programming tools,  but yes, you can both supervise a device and then manage it by MDM. Apps that are installed during the supervision process are managed separately to apps that the user installs using the iTunes Store. iCloud is separate though; if the app supports iCloud and the user is signed into iCloud then it can use the users iCloud regardless of installation source